# mySQL insert statement NOT working?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I've been looking around for an answer. I've been cross-referencing my code with others. And I don't seem to see any blatant errors...

My database does not update, my database does nothing. Oh and the page also does nothing too...... It's frustrating because, I'm just using notepad ++ and can't pinpoint the error. I'm using XAmpp as well, and, all the values match the ones I have made.

```
    The .post statement (Using jQuery 1.7.1):
    //Make sure DOM is loaded before running jQuery based code: [STATIC CODE]
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#uploadbtn').click(function() {

        //Parse name and song.
        var name = $('#songname').val();
        var song =  $('#songupload').val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'db/upload.php?name=' + name + 'song=' + song,
            success: function(res) {
                $('#nav-playlist').html(res);
            }
        }   
        )

    });

});



Now here is my php file:

<?php

/*Connection to database.
   First with mysql_connect (to log in). Then selecting the master database.
*/
echo "Upload.php accessed...";
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die ( mysql_error() );
$database = mysql_select_db("betadb") or die( mysql_error() );

//Properties (to be inserted into database).
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]); 
$song = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["song"]);

//Insertion formula for mySQL
$query = "INSERT INTO songs SET name= '$name' song='$song' ";

if (mysql_query($query)){
echo "Success";
} 
else {

}

?>
```

ADDITIONAL NOTES:
the song table consists of id, name, song (in that order).
Song is the BLOB datatype, as it is used to store .mp3s

Comment: Try returning mysql_error(), also see SQL injection. Your implementation is decidedly insecure.

Comment: what does your songs table look like?

Comment: did u try to output the query and run it on your mysql client separately ?

Comment: `('',` is to avoid inserting id? this is not a good idea

Comment: Yes '' is to avoid inserting id. I've switched to set. Still not luck.
My songs table is still empty OH, and song is a BLOB datatype. Since I want an actual .mp3

Comment: Some things you need to think about: max_post_size in PHP, the fact that you don't know PHP and the simple fact that you are not trying enough to answer to your own questions. Oh, and try to be a little bit more polite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the following line

```
data    : 'db/upload.php?name='+name+'song='+song,
```

data should be an array containing the values, such as

```
var data
data["name"] = name
data["song"] = song
```

The $.ajax call is also missing the url parameter which is needed to carry out the request

```
url: 'db/upload.php'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify your column.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO songs (youcoulmn1,youcolumn2) VALUES ('$name', '$song')";
```

See also:

[PHP MySQL Insert Into](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

in order to debug it
1) do `print_r($_POST);` to check do you have anything to insert
2) then instead of
`$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die ("Unsucessful");`
  do
`$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());`
to get the exact error and search for the error fix

Comment: I get nothing... and nothing?

Comment: it means the data to be inserted is not fetched properly as print_r($_POST) has nothing in this case. To ensure it, hard code the values and if hard-coding works in this case then trace where the $_POST lost its data

Answer (score 1):

```
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]); //Assign to name & song variables.
    $song = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["song"]);

//Insertion formula for mySQL
$query = "INSERT INTO songs VALUES ('$name', '$song')";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die ("Unsucessful");
```

Answer (score 1):

had better using `SET`, is more easier for some conditions, and for Jquery Command use `$.ajax`, you can try this one

for javascript / JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#uploadbtn').click(function(){
        var name = $('#songname').val();
        var song =  $('#songupload').val();
        $.ajax({
            type    :'POST',
            data    : 'db/upload.php?name='+name+'song='+song,
            success :function(res){
                $('#nav-playlist').html(res);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and for Insert command in the php

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]); 
$song = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["song"]);

$query = "INSERT INTO songs SET name='$name' song='$song'";
if(mysql_query($query)){
    // some process if success
}else{
    // some proses if not
}
```

use mysql_real_escape_string to filtering data before insert to database

Comment: Song is a blob value. Should that change anything?

Comment: Oh and still no luck. I assumed that the post method would've been acceptable, but, passing data like the way you've specified seems safer.

Comment: do you trying to save data with the blob type ? and trying to get the value of the song from song variable in field input ? how you read the song data ? i mean how you could read song data using `song: $('#songupload').val()` is that posible ? try to read song data with out inserting to database first, using `print_r($_POST)` to see post value

Comment: Yes I am saving an .mp3 (Cream - Crossroads). And that does shit all? Man my php file doesn't do anything it's a pile of crap.

Comment: Oh, and, yes, re-evaluating an .mp3 using .val is fine. Javascript supports long string literals so I could convert the .mp3 to byte code then reparse it when I get it back from the database to be listened to.

Atleast that is what google code tells me. But I could be wrong (a limitation on the mySQL side maybe).

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes around variables might be causing the problem.. check it..

Comment: Brah it did nothing. Like seriously, none of this shit does anything. I've scrapped the project. Xampp sucks. Like it says server is up but doesn't tell me shit if things are working.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, the line

```
$query = "INSERT INTO songs SET name= '$name' song='$song' ";
```

should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO songs SET name= '$name', song='$song' ";
```

Pay attention to commas!

And also:

```
data: 'db/upload.php?name=' + name + 'song=' + song,
```

should be at least:

```
data: 'db/upload.php?name=' + name + '&song=' + song,
```

because there is no delimiter between fields right now.